# pyreadstat expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not InMemoryUploadedFile

Tags: python, django, pandas, django-rest-framework, spss

Trying to make endpoint that can read uploaded .sav (SPSS) file and create model with data from it. For getting data from it I'm using pyreadstat library. But now when I'm trying to run it I have an error `expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not InMemoryUploadedFile`

How I can change this code so pyreadstat can correctly read the given file?

```
from rest_framework import generics, status
import pandas as pd
import pyreadstat
from rest_framework.response import Response

from .models import Research, Data
from .serializers import FileUploadSerializer, SaveFileSerializer

class UploadFileView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = FileUploadSerializer
    
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        file = serializer.validated_data['file']
        df, meta = pyreadstat.read_sav(file, user_missing=True)
        json_df = df.to_json(orient='table')
        
        rsch = Research.objects.get(pk=1)
        Data.objects.create(research=rsch, data={})
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/files/uploads/#

Comment: Please follow up, upvote, and mark an answer as accepted if it answered your questio.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```py
pyreadstat.read_sav(file, user_missing=True)
```

To this:

```py
pyreadstat.read_sav(file.getvalue(), user_missing=True)
```

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

Django [uploaded files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/files/uploads/#) are *mostly* file like, and they only proxy certain methods.  See the [`FileProxyMixin`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/core/files/utils.py#L27) source for more details on specific methods, if you are curious.

To get the uploaded contents, use the `read()` method:

```
file = serializer.validated_data['file']
contents = file.read()
df, meta = pyreadstat.read_sav(contents, user_missing=True)
```

In this case you are getting an `InMemoryUploadFile` but this could change if Django decides to write to disk due to the upload being too large.

Documentation on django uploaded file objects:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/files/uploads/#.